# Symfony Forms comparison between objects used as choice values and underlying data

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm using Symfony 2.8, but the question is not specific to this version.
Let's say I have `MyThingsFormType` with this field:

```
$builder->add(
    'things',
    ChoiceType::class,
    [
        'multiple' => true,
        'choices_as_values' => true,
        'choices' => [
            'Thing no.20' => new Thing(20),
            'Thing no.21' => new Thing(21),
            'Thing no.22' => new Thing(22),
        ],
    ]
);
```

and `'data_class' => MyThings::class`.

The class `MyThings` is defined as:

```
class MyThings
   private Thing[] $myThings
```

And when I create my form I pass an object with some pre-populated choices, like:

```
$form = $this->formFactory->create(
    new MyThingsFormType(), 
    new MyThings([new Thing(21)])
);
```

The point is, I would expect the choice `Thing no.21` to be pre-populated in the view, because the underlying `MyThings` object I pass to the form, does have that object in the `$myThings` array... I know it's not *the same* object, but just one with the same data, and apparently Symfony does a strict comparison, so it does not consider that choice as being pre-selected...

So, what would be the quickest & cleanest way to customise that behaviour, so I can consider pre-selected the choices that have the same data, even if they're not *the same* objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution in [this response to a GitHub issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17939#issuecomment-192175184).

> The good thing about choice_value is that Symfony will also use this closure to compare two different object instances for equality.

The trick is simply to use the `choice_value` option to determine the value of the choice. Something like:

```
'choice_value' => function (Thing $thing) {
    return $thing->getNumber();
},
```

This method will be called on the `Thing` objects used as choices, and on the ones passed as data, so they will be considered equal even if they are different instances...